# mass-assignment issues in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting the following error even and unable to correct it can someone please help.

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in HomePageController#add_to_cart
Can't mass-assign protected attributes for CartItem: customer_id, product_id, quantity_ordered

Extracted source (around line #7):

def add_product(id, product_id, quantity_ordered)
    cart_item =CartItem.new(
      :customer_id => id, 
      :product_id => product_id, 
      :quantity_ordered => quantity_ordered)

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :cart_items,  :dependent=> :destroy
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :product_id, :quantity_ordered


  def add_product(id, product_id, quantity_ordered)
    cart_item =CartItem.new(
      :customer_id => id, 
      :product_id => product_id, 
      :quantity_ordered => quantity_ordered)
    cart_items  <<  cart_item     #appends a value
    cart_item             #returns a value
 end

  def total_price
    cart_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.sub_total }
  end
end
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using `protected_attributes` (ie. attr_accessible) in Rails 4, you should be using `strong_parameters`.

Comment: has any answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Rails-3-style protected attributes, you'll need to install the [protected_attributes gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes).

As pointed out by Rafael Fiuza, you will have to use [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in Rails 4 if you don't want to install another gem just to get the Rails-3 way of protecting attributes.

If you use strong parameters, your code in HomePageController will look something like:

```
def add_to_cart
  #code for defining @customer
  @customer.cart_items.create(cart_item_params)
end

def cart_item_params
  params.require(:cart_item).permit(:product_id, :quantity_ordered)
end
```

You don't need to define `#add_product` in your Customer model or you could refactor it to make use of `cart_items.create(cart_item_attributes` instead to make it a lot shorter and cleaner.

If you're already using the `protected_attributes` gem, you'll need to add below code in your CartItem model instead of in your Customer model:

```
class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :product_id, :quantity_ordered

  #other code
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `attr_accessible` line should be in your CartItem model, not the Customer model

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your CartItem.rb file you should have something like this:

```
class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer 
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :product_id, :quantity_ordered
```

The attr_accessible is necessary in your `CartItem` model file, so that you can assign those attributes when you create a new instance of `CartItem`.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 4,mass assignments protection is in controllers using strong params. Check out http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html.

Comment: This is true, but the error in that case would be different than the one he reported

Comment: if he's still using attr_accessible, then he isn't using strong_parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is strangely why do you get the `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` exception. Although, the mass assignment is a probable vulnerability of you site, it is need to be fixed with a few steps:

1. Replace declaration of all ids in a model from `attr_accessible` to `attr_protected` operator:

   > attr_protected :customer_id, :product_id
2. Do not pass id fields into the constructor of the model, which can be `new`, 'create', etc:

   > cart_item = CartItem.new quantity_ordered: quantity_ordered
3. Possibly, do not assign ids fields directly, use idless assignments instead:

   > cart_item.customer = customer
   >   cart_item.product = product
4. Also, you shell specify `customer_id`, `product_id` fields for `CartItem` model, not for the `Customer`.

As result we get the following code for the `CartItem` model:

```
class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :customer_id, :product_id, :quantity_ordered
end
```

And for the `Customer` model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product customer, product, quantity_ordered
    cart_item = CartItem.new quantity_ordered: quantity_ordered
    cart_item.customer = customer
    cart_item.product = product
    cart_item.save!
    cart_items << cart_item     #appends the value
    cart_item                   #returns the value
  end

  def total_price
    cart_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.sub_total }
  end
end
```

Additionally, please check out more accurately about mass-assignment vulnerability [here](http://railspikes.com/2008/9/22/is-your-rails-application-safe-from-mass-assignment) and [here](http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2008/03/11/use-attr_protected-or-we-will-hack-you/).

Comment: @doug-kandl has my answer been helpful?